# multiple same result when the button is triggered multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax

may ajax append 2 same results on the table when i accidentally double click on the button. is there a way to stop ajax from returning 2 or more result when i click the search button? i tried to abort the ajax but the result is the same. im just a newbie in ajax so help me guys

```
$("#btn_searchadmin").click(function(){

    var adminname = $("#tb_admin").val();
    var ajax;


    if(ajax){

      ajax.abort();
    }

     ajax = $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "manage_deped_searchadmin.php",
                    dataType:'json',
                    cache:false,
                    data:{'adminname': adminname},


                    beforeSend: function(data){

                      $('#tbl_search').html('');


                    },

                    success: function(data){

                      $("#btn_searchadmin").bind('click');

                      $.each(data, function(i, item) {

                        $('#tbl_search').append("<tr><td>"+data[i].adminfname+"</td>  <td>"+data[i].adminlname+"</td>");

                      });
                    }
          });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to this. I will give you a text answer rather than code.

- Disable the button as soon as it is clicked, and re-enable it when the ajax has responded (eg in the `complete` handler);
- Leave the button enabled but abort any unresolved previous ajax call resulting from an earlier click.

Both of these approaches are valid and which you choose depends entirely on the application.

- Choose approach 1 if a second ajax call must be disallowed until the first has completed.
- Choose approach 2 if a second ajax call should be allowed to override an earlier one.

Comment: thats why i used the ajax.abort(); inside the if so if the "ajax" variable is defined it wont do the ajax but will prioritize the first call. but i guess it doesnt work. did i do it wrong?

Comment: Declare `var ajax;` outside the handler.

Comment: because its inside the handler. so if im going to click the ajax will return in to undefined always cuz its inside the handler therefore the ajax will still be called. but when i put it outside and make it as a global the ajax calls resides on the variable thats why it falls inside the if because it is already defined. am i right?

Comment: You're nearly right. I would phrase my explanation as follows. "If `ajax` is declared inside the click handler, then it is local to that handler. Subsequent clicks will create their own local `ajax` and will have no means of addressing the `ajax` created by earlier calls. By declaring `ajax` in an outer scope, all instances of the click handler have read/write access to it."

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a lock to the click event, in order to prevent such case.

```
(function() {
  var lock = false;
  $("#btn_searchadmin").click(function() {
    if (!lock) {
      lock = true;
      // do something
      // unlock at the end of callback
    }
  });
})()
```

Comment: you don't have to unbind, but it's a better approach